# Bitcoin-qt and lost local blockchain files

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-core

For some reason I've lost all data in my `.bitcoin` directory except the `wallet.dat` file. Now bitcoin-qt shows 0 balance, and it's 5 years behind sync. Is this possible to restore coins in this case?

Answer (score 1):

If the blockchain files are gone, then your Bitcoin client has no way to match up the keys in your wallet with the transactions in the blockchain. Remember the balance is not stored *in* the wallet, but the keys in the wallet can be matched with transactions in the blockchain to calculate your balance.

Fortunately, the blockchain files are public and the same for everybody so you now just have to wait for them to download. It may take quite some time (days or more). You could try downloading a torrent of the blockchain to speed up the process, but this is optional.

Comment: In other words, since you still have `wallet.dat`, you still have your coins, and once you have synced the blockchain you will be able to see them.  This would be an excellent time to make sure your `wallet.dat` is backed up.

Comment: I have moved wallet.dat and sync is completed. Though still balance is 0 coins...

Comment: Where did you move wallet.dat? That wasn't part of the answer. If you move wallet.dat somewhere else then your Bitcoin client won't read it and you will have 0 balance.